# How do I convert numpy mgrid function as a function?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the way how `numpy.mgrid` is used.

```
grid = np.mgrid[x1:y1:100j , x2:y2:100j, ..., xn:yn:100j]
```

However, I find this structure very irritating. Therefore, I would like to create function `f` which works as follows:

```
f([(x1,y1,100),...,(xn,yn,100)]) = np.mgrid[x1:y1:100j , x2:y2:100j, ..., xn:yn:100j]
```

How can I create `f`?

(Here is the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3740af94f888cf5708e7cfa18170b7c4069b1f17/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py) for np.mgrid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over each item passed to `f` and make a slice out of it with `slice`, and to get `100j` from `100`, multiply `100` by `1j`:

```
def f(items):
    slices = [slice(i[0], i[1], 1j * i[2]) for i in items]
    return np.mgrid[slices]
```

Output:

```
>>> np.all( f([(1,2,5), (2,3,5)]) == np.mgrid[1:2:5j, 2:3:5j] )
True
```

You could make calling the function even simpler by using `*items` instead of `items`:

```
def f(*items):
    slices = [slice(i[0], i[1], 1j * i[2]) for i in items]
    return np.mgrid[slices]
```

Output:

```
>>> np.all( f([1,2,5], [2,3,5]) == np.mgrid[1:2:5j, 2:3:5j] )
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`mgrid` is an instance of a cute class that lets us use indexing notation.  Under the covers it uses `np.linspace` (or `np.arange`) to generate the ranges.

```
In [29]: x1,y1 = 0,1; x2,y2 = 1,3
In [30]: np.mgrid[x1:y1:3j, x2:y2:4j]
Out[30]: 
array([[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.5       , 0.5       , 0.5       , 0.5       ],
        [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ]],

       [[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ],
        [1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ],
        [1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]]])
```

`meshgrid` is the function equivalent.  I suspect it was the original function, and `mgrid` (and `ogrid`) was secondary version:

```
In [31]: np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x1,y1,3), np.linspace(x2,y2,4), indexing='ij')
Out[31]: 
[array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        [1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ]]),
 array([[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ],
        [1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ],
        [1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]])]
```

`mgrid` creates a n-d array; `meshgrid` returns a list of arrays.  Otherwise they are equivalent.  `np.array(Out[31])` creates the array.

### sparse versions

`ogrid` produces a "sparse" pair of arrays that, with `broadcasting`, functions the same way:

```
In [37]: np.ogrid[x1:y1:3j, x2:y2:4j]
Out[37]: 
[array([[0. ],
        [0.5],
        [1. ]]),
 array([[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]])]
```

`meshgrid` has an equivalent `sparse` mode:

```
In [38]: np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x1,y1,3), np.linspace(x2,y2,4), indexing='ij',
    ...: sparse=True)
Out[38]: 
[array([[0. ],
        [0.5],
        [1. ]]),
 array([[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]])]
```

We can create the same pair of arrays with:

```
In [39]: np.ix_(np.linspace(x1,y1,3), np.linspace(x2,y2,4))
Out[39]: 
(array([[0. ],
        [0.5],
        [1. ]]),
 array([[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]]))
```

or even:

```
In [40]: (np.linspace(x1,y1,3)[:,None], np.linspace(x2,y2,4)[None,:])
Out[40]: 
(array([[0. ],
        [0.5],
        [1. ]]),
 array([[1.        , 1.66666667, 2.33333333, 3.        ]]))
```